# BouncyCastle RSA Probabilistic Signature Scheme with Recovery

Tags: c#, bouncycastle, crypto++

The following code sign message with recovery, How implementation with C# BouncyCastle?

```
std::vector<unsigned char> data{ 1,2,3,4,5,6 };

CryptoPP::AutoSeededRandomPool rng;
CryptoPP::InvertibleRSAFunction params;
params.GenerateRandomWithKeySize(rng, 2048);

CryptoPP::RSA::PrivateKey privateKey(params);
CryptoPP::RSA::PublicKey publicKey(params);
CryptoPP::RSASS<CryptoPP::PSSR, CryptoPP::SHA1>::Signer signer(privateKey);

CryptoPP::SecByteBlock signature(signer.MaxSignatureLength(data.size()));

unsigned long signatureLen = signer.SignMessageWithRecovery(rng, &data[0],
    data.size(), NULL, 0, signature);

std::vector<unsigned char> encrypted;
encrypted.assign(signatureLen, 0);
memcpy(&encrypted[0], signature.m_ptr, signatureLen);
```

Comment: Note that this code is about PSS-R or PSS with message recovery. Comment just so people searching for PSS-R can actually find it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the [`Iso9796d2PssSigner`](http://www.bouncycastle.org/docs/docs1.5on/index.html?org/bouncycastle/crypto/signers/ISO9796d2PSSSigner.html) class in the [`Org.BouncyCastle.Crypto.Signers`](http://www.bouncycastle.org/docs/docs1.5on/index.html?org/bouncycastle/crypto/signers/ISO9796d2PSSSigner.html) namespace should probably do what you want. You can find examples of use in the source of ISO9796Test.cs.